# sql multiple subqueries in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, subquery

I have the following tables:

address_components (table)

```
ADDRESS_ID       STREET_NUMBER            STREET_NAME
-----------------------------------------------------
001              1402                     Motz
002              505                      31st
003              4100                     Stimmel
```

attributes (table)

```
ID              ATTRIBUTE_DEFINITION_ID         VALUE
----------------------------------------------------------------
001             Lot                             546
001             SubDiv                          Avondale Spring
002             Lot                             546 
002             SubDiv                          Garden
003             Lot                             131
003             SubDiv                          Avondale Spring
```

And the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
    street_number,street_name
FROM 
    address_components a, attributes attr 
WHERE 
    a.address_id = attr.id 
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM attributes 
                WHERE attr.attribute_definition_id = 'Lot'   
                  AND attr.value = '546') 
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM attributes 
                WHERE attr.attribute_definition_id = 'SubDiv' 
                  AND attr.value = 'Avondale spring')
```

I am trying to select address_components row "001" because I am trying to retrieve rows that have both attribute entries of "lot = 546" and SubDiv = Avondale Spring". Not either but both attributes must exist.

The query is returning no matches; however, when I query using a single subquery (eliminate 1 of the 2 subqueries) the requested rows are returned for that single query.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT top 1 a.street_number,a.street_name from address_components a
              inner join attributes k on  a.ADDRESS_ID=k.ID
              WHERE k.ATTRIBUTE_DEFINITION_ID in('Lot','SubDiv')  AND
              k.value in('546','Avondale Spring')
```

Comment: What if rows are `001 | Lot | Avondale Spring || 001 | SubDiv | 546`? @GordonLinoff's answer is better.

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind the query is fine.  But you don't need two tables in the `from` clause; you want *correlated subqueries*:

```
SELECT a.street_number, a.street_name
FROM address_components a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM attributes attr
              WHERE a.address_id = attr.id AND attr.attribute_definition_id = 'Lot' AND  attr.value = '546'
             ) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM attributes attr
              WHERE a.address_id = attr.id AND attr.attribute_definition_id = 'SubDiv' AND attr.value = 'Avondale spring'
             );
```